# How do I get JSON back from a Sqlite text field?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I've managed to store some JSON to a field in my sqlite database, the length of the TEXT (in the sqlite docs theres no limit on a text field size) field is 1337.

I've even tried varchar, but again my app crashes with SGABRT. I don't get any other error details.

Looking at the record in a sqlite utility the data is complete and fine and my query shown below works.

I've even substituted why query and the code does work with a record in another table.

**I know I should be using Core Data but this is an existing app and I can't convert it at this time.**

No sure how to proceed ?

```
NSString *ret = @"";
const char *sql = "select value from MyTable where item = 'json'";

sqlite3 *database;
int result = sqlite3_open(... db path function ...], &database);
... snip in not db and error code ...
sqlite3_stmt *statementTMP;

sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statementTMP, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statementTMP) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
             (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statementTMP, 1)]; << Fails here
    }
sqlite3_finalize(statementTMP);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

EDIT

Start of my JSON data

```
{"lowestday":"31","pfAppAdvAcSel":-1,"styleselec
```

Further EDIT

```
        char *test = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statementTMP, 1);
        NSLog(@"value = %s", test); << (NULL)
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of some of the JSON?

Comment: Get the char* value back.  First test to see if it's null (most likely is).  If not null, print the value using %s before you convert to NSString.

Comment: ahhhh should be 0 and not 1 for column id :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `sqlite3_column_text()` incorrectly. Since you are selecting only a single column (value), there is only one column from which you can extract text. In SQLite3, column numbers begin with 0, rather than 1. Therefore, you should change the second argument of your call to `sqlite3_column_text` with 0 instead of 1.